# Does AWS Timestream LAST_VALUE support ignore nulls arguments?

Tags: amazon-timestream

I'm trying to get use TimeStream to get the last non null value using `last_value` but so far haven't had any luck.

I've tried:

```
last_value(power ignore nulls) OVER (
        PARTITION BY deviceId ORDER BY time asc range BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND CURRENT row)
```

and also:

```
last_value(power) ignore nulls OVER (
        PARTITION BY deviceId ORDER BY time asc range BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND CURRENT row)
```

as per some documentation I've seen regarding SQL/Athena etc but am getting errors on the query.

Does Timestream support `ignore nulls`? I'm hoping it does as it will make a difference for my query.

Comment: Did you receive any error while running above queries? If yes share those details. I believe last_value(power ignore nulls) OVER (PARTITION BY deviceId ORDER BY time asc range BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND CURRENT row) should work.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes I do get an error message, but unfortunately not very helpful: `The query syntax is invalid at line 21:34`